# How to convert below style to styled component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9agwom?file=index.js

I'm trying to convert the below style to styled component for a `third party library`.

```
   **Using <div className="grid"> istead of <StyledDiv> works fine.** 

  .grid table tr th,
  .grid table tr td {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .grid table tr th:nth-child(2),
  .grid table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 200%;
  }


 <StyledDiv>
    <Grid
      rows={data}
      columns={columns}
    >
      <TableView />
      <TableHeaderRow />
    </Grid>
  </StyledDiv>
```

How do I convert this to styled component? I tried below but it does not work.

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  color: red;

  & table tr th,
  & table tr td {
    width: 100%;
  };
  & table tr th:nth-child(2),
  & table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 200%;
  }
`;
```

I do not see anything generated except the style for `color:red`.
Also, is there a way to get some sort of compile error if there is a problem or debug the styled component?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a sandbox? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-t80qj

Comment: Here the is the code - > https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9agwom?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```js
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  color: red;

  table {
    tr {
      th, td {
       width: 100%; 
       &:nth-child(2) {
          width: 200%;
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```